# Importing .NET Namespaces to an empty Visual C++ project

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio-2010

I've created an empty C++ project in Visual Studio. When attempting to add .NET references through the Project Properties page, the 'Add Reference' window only displays the project tab:

[image]

I've stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252105/visual-studio-2010-add-reference-tabs-will-only-give-me-projects-no-browse-a) thread, but I couldn't get this to work even with the information in the accepted answer.

How would I go about adding such .NET references to my project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to add references to .Net assemblies you should have a C++ project with CLR support (/clr or similar).

In order to activate Common Language Runtime Support open the properties for your project go to the Configuration Properties\General item and select one of the options for "Common Language Runtime Support" that suits your need

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have created a *native* C++ project, which most assuredly cannot do anything with .NET- unless you want to host your own CLR and that kind of owch. You must change it to C++/CLI, and then you can add .NET references.