# Adding a DLL to my Visual Studio project (missing Browse)

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll

I am trying to figure out how to add a DLL file to my project but every resource I have found does not work for me. Typically, people say to click `References` then `Add Reference` then click on the `Browse` tab which I don't have. I started off by copying my DLL file to my resources folder but here is what my `Add Reference` menu looks like. Also, as a quick note I am using Visual Studio 2019 and this problem exists for every single one of my projects regardless of the starting template.

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265879/unable-to-browse-to-include-reference-in-a-visual-studio-c-dll-project-any-w

Comment: @Motomotes Nope that does not work I already read that post and the answer requires me to use a section called ``Project Defaults`` which does not exist in Visual Studio 2019 or requires me to do something in order to access it.

Comment: Maybe under `Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General` page

Comment: @Motomotes Ok yes that does appear to have the same options, but it does not produce the same results I tried setting it to ``No Common Language Runtime Support`` and to ``Command Language Runtime Support (/clr)`` but I still done get the Browse option.